# Android publishing issues (application package?)

Tags: android, eclipse, package

So I made an app for android, debugged it and it was a really great experience overall.  However the app has a problem now.  I went to publish the app and it told me I couldn't publish the app under the package name com.exmaple.ect, so I went to change it, no problem there.  However foolishly when I changed the application package I did it manually and forgot to change the manifest so when it published, the app would crash.  So I went back and updated it and I re-saved and went to tools to "export signed application package".

I then proceeded to update but realized I made a mistake and named the package wrong, so I went to fix it.  It then published fine.  However upon publishing the icon got taken out of the app so I had to (for a fourth time, sorry I'm still a beginner) update.

So now I update the app with Icon.. I updated the app after "export signed application package" again and when it went to upload the app onto my test phone, there are now 4 app icons on both my Android smartphone and when I click, one of them doesn't work as before, the other one without an icon, the other with an icon that works.  However when I click the one that works it then says "Complete using action" with the four different package names.  How can I get it so only the one that works is the app downloaded onto users phones?

As usual, I'm very appreciative to all responses.  Each prior version is still showing.  Could it be that I'm not suppose to "export signed application package" each time I tried updating?

Answer (score 0):

If each app has a different package name, it is considered a completely different app. The package name is what identifies your application from all of the others, and is what makes each individual application uniques.

For example: if you were to release an app with whatever package name, this package name must stay the same for the lifetime of the app. If the package name were to change, it is released as a completely different app. Thus, your users will not be informed of an update, as it technically didn't receive an update.

Hope this helps, happy coding!

Comment: So that is why when they install my one app, they get 4.  Is there any way I can fix this? Even using the eclipse emulator I see 4 apps as opposed to my one and when I click the working app, it posts "Complete Using Action".  What would be a way to fix this?  

Thank you for your reply!

Comment: No, that's not what he's saying at all.

Comment: To make sure everything is clean, uninstall all the apps you find that you created on either your device and on the emulator image. So uninstall the 4 apps from the your device and uninstall the 4 apps from your image. Or if you want with your emulator, just create a new image/AVD from scratch and delete the previous image, that will get rid of the 4 applications on your image. Then after that, you'll see that once you run the app once, only one application will be there, not 4. And as long as you don't change the package name, any update you make to that one one app, only one icon will show

Comment: Will check out what you said and report back, thank you!

Comment: StackOverflow is having sever problems right now. May be, you didn't see my previous comment 19 seconds before yours.

Comment: Yeah it came after I posted, hence why I changed the comment.

Comment: It worked on the emulator, now only thing that's left it to publish (update) and hope for the best!

Comment: Thank you Stephen for extending on what I said and clarifying for him. As I was saying, you must have had 4 different applications, because the older apps (before you changed the package name) remained because ideally, they were 4 unique apps, dictated by the package name itself. I'm glad you got your problem resolved. If this helped, accept answer so confusion is caused.